# Excel Drop Down + search function

Tags: excel, vba

I have a drop down with a lot of list in it.
Its taking a long time just to search / scrolling down through the list.

is there any way to make it easier? For example: I can extend the scroll range longer (which is currently 8 items only), or maybe some sort of AutoComplete by typing the item name.

Its just basically to search the item easier in the drop down list.
Thanks!

Comment: what type of dropdown is it?

Comment: are you talking about a data/validation dropdown? for just searching in an excel sheet use the autofilter which (in Excel 2007/2010) has all the functionality you are addressing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

1. Cascading dropdown (such as [xls cascading lookup based on pivot table style datasource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676893/xls-cascading-lookup-based-on-pivot-table-style-datasource) and http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal02.html)
2. Use a formula in the Named Range for your List Validation that will *simulate* an autocomplete

   1. Create a named range `Test` with this kind of formula :
      `=OFFSET($A$2,MATCH($C$1&"*",$A:$A,0)-2,0,COUNT($A:$A))`
   2. Where:

      - your list of data is in column A (values should be sorted alphabetically)
      - the current cell where you are applying the validation on is C1
   3. Then you can:

      - start typing the text you want in cell A1, for instance `Wash`
      - then click on the drop-down list
      - the dropdown list will begin at `Whashington` and so on

I've just translated it from one of my old workbook so tell me if anything doesn't work.

[EDIT] Just a quick test seem to make it work (you should also restrain the end of the list for the beauty of the formula)

[image: Screenshot]

[image: Example with Washington]