# Excel searchable data validation dropdown lists

Tags: excel, vba

There are two ways to make drop down list in Excel:

1. Data validation list
2. Combobox form control

Now in my project I have Data validation dropdown lists wich can be too long and I want to add search functionality for it. I've find some solutions but only for combobox control, which not applicable for my Excel document, because theese dropdown lists should be repeated in each row:

[image]

Is there any possible solution to add search functionality to datavalidation dropdown list?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vkPoViUhkxU

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18605402/excel-drop-down-search-function

Comment: This is what you need https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eB7aedJ9RVI