# Searchable Dropdown List in Excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to create a "searchable dropdown list" in Excel

Essentially, instead of the user choosing from one of 100 items in a dropdown list, I want them to be able to type in a few letters, and only the results matching that will show up in the dropdown.

I've come across two solutions:

- the FILTER function, which is only coming available to my version of Excel in July
- Pivot tables, which are quite clunky (changes colors, column sizes, etc. when I touch it)

Are you aware of any other options for a searchable dropdown list?

Thank you

Comment: May be [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30229264/9808063)  and so [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vkPoViUhkxU)

Comment: Thank you @NareshBhople this was the best video