# Excel search from list and select - not dropdown

Tags: excel, vba

I've looked quite at a few examples online.  Everything I find is in combo box drop down.  My boss wants to type in excel, for example in **A1** *123456* and then it must auto filter the data from a list all starting with *123456*.  Then he selects the option he wants and move on to cell A2.

All the examples I've tried is for a combo box, that is not what he needs.  Can someone please point me in the right direction?  Help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You didn't say what list or range you're filtering as the user types a value into A1. However, look at writing your code to catch the `Worksheet_Change` event for that worksheet. You can focus on the user's entry in A1 and then continually apply a filter to whatever list or range you need.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel Drop Down + search function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18605402/excel-drop-down-search-function)

Comment: Check out that link; it's an ingenious solution. I had looked at that previously for exactly your use-case; I couldn't find anything else that didn't use VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Building off of the answer to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13934821/vba-for-filtering-columns), I came up with something that should work. I had a similar request recently; I think it's a nice feel as opposed to the usual UI for filters.

My setup looks like this:

[image: demo setup]

As @PeterT mentions, you will need to use the Worksheet_Change event for that specific sheet, which looks like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim filterField
    filterField = 0

    If Target.Address = "$B$2" Then
        filterField = 1
    ElseIf Target.Address = "$C$2" Then
        filterField = 2
    ElseIf Target.Address = "$D$2" Then
        filterField = 3
    ElseIf Target.Address = "$E$2" Then
        filterField = 4
    End If

    If filterField <> 0 Then
        Call UpdateFilter(filterField, Target.Value)
    End If
End Sub
```

There's a lot of cleaning up and simplifying that can be done in the code, this version is quick and dirty for this specific example - should not be hard to generalize, but if you need help, leave a comment.

You need some more VBA to update the filters:

```
Public Sub UpdateFilter(filterField, strValue)

    If strValue = "" Then
        Range("B4").AutoFilter field:=filterField, Criteria1:="<>"
    Else
        strValue = strValue & "*"
        Range("B4").AutoFilter field:=filterField, Criteria1:=strValue
    End If
End Sub
```

End result looks like this:

[image: Full Text]

Adding a '*' to the end of the string allows partial matches ("Begins With..."):

[image: Partial Text]